# Convergence of $\sum(n^3\sin^2n)^{-1}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series

I saw a while ago in a book by Clifford Pickover, that whether the [Flint Hills series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FlintHillsSeries.html) $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3\sin^2 n}$ converges is open.

I would think that the question of its convergence is really about the density in $\mathbb N$ of the sequence of numerators of the standard convergent approximations to $\pi$ (which, in itself, seems like an interesting question). Naively, the point is that if $n$ is "close" to a whole multiple of $\pi$, then $1/(n^3\sin^2n)$ is "close" to $\frac1{\pi^2 n}$.

[Numerically there is some evidence that only some of these values of $n$ affect the overall behavior of the series. For example, letting $S(k)=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac1{n^3\sin^2n}$, one sees that $S(k)$ does not change much in the interval, say, $[50,354]$, with $S(354)<5$. However, $S(355)$ is close to $30$, and note that $355$ is very close to $113\pi$. On the other hand, $S(k)$ does not change much from that point until $k=100000$, where I stopped looking.]

I imagine there is a large body of work within which the question of the convergence of this series would fall naturally, and I would be interested in knowing something about it. Sadly, I'm terribly ignorant in these matters. Even knowing where to look for some information on approximations of $\pi$ by rationals, or an *ad hoc* approach just tailored to this specific series would be interesting as well.

Comment: If we replace $n^3$ with $n^2$, what happens?  (This isn't a rhetorical question; I'm honestly wondering if anyone knows the answer.)  More generally, consider sums $F(a,b) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/(n^a |sin n|^b)$.  Clearly $F(a,b)$ increases with $a$ and decreases with $b$, but when is $F(a,b)$ known to be either finite or infinite?

Comment: The convergence of this general form is related to
the irrationality measure of $\pi$, that is the infimum of exponents
$k$ such that $|\pi-a/b|<1/b^k$ has only finitely many integer
solutions. (For $|\sin n|$ to be small, $n$ must be close to an
integer multiple $m\pi$ of $\pi$ and then $|\sin n|\sim m|\pi-n/m|$.)
Results are known (see for instance
http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/IrrationalityMeasure.html)
and these will yield explicit values of $a$, $b$ for which the series
converges, but the proofs are delicate and don't yield the best
expected result.

Comment: $n^3sin^2{n}<10^{-n}$, Does n which satisfies this inequality exist infinitely? This is more high level question.

Comment: A variant that I've considered is to study the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{W(\operatorname{exp}(n))^3\sin^2n}$, where $W(x)$ denotes the principal value of the Lambert $W$-function. I don't know if it have a good mathematical content (I'm not a professional mathematician) or if it is in the literature. I add it if you @MichaelLugo want to think about it, ins't required a response for this comment. You can see  a partial sum in Wolfram Alpha online calculator with the code `sum 1/( ProductLog[e^n]^3 sin^2 n), from n=1 to 1000`  written in Wolfram Language

Answer (score 132, accepted):

As Robin Chapman mentions in his comment, the difficulty of investigating
the convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3\sin^2n}
$$
is due to lack of knowledge about the behavior of $|n\sin n|$ as $n\to\infty$,
while the latter is related to rational approximations to $\pi$ as follows.

Neglecting the terms of the sum for which $n|\sin n|\ge n^\varepsilon$
($\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary),
as they all contribute only to the `convergent part' of the sum, the question
is equivalent to the one for the series
$$
\sum_{n:n|\sin n|< n^\varepsilon}\frac1{n^3\sin^2n}.
\qquad(1)
$$
For any such $n$, let $q=q(n)$ minimizes the distance $|\pi q-n|\le\pi/2$.
Then
$$
\sin|\pi q-n|=|\sin n|< \frac1{n^{1-\varepsilon}},
$$
so that $|\pi q-n|\le C_1/n^{1-\varepsilon}$ for some absolute constant $C_1$
(here we use that $\sin x\sim x$ as $x\to0$). Therefore,
$$
\biggl|\pi-\frac nq\biggr|<\frac{C_1}{qn^{-\varepsilon}},
$$
equivalently
$$
\biggl|\pi-\frac nq\biggr|<\frac{C_2}{n^{2-\varepsilon}}
\quad\text{or}\quad
\biggl|\pi-\frac nq\biggr|<\frac{C_2'}{q^{2-\varepsilon}}
$$
(because $n/q\approx\pi$) for all $n$ participating in the sum (1).
It is now clear that the convergence of the sum (1) depends
on how often we have
$$
\biggl|\pi-\frac nq\biggr|<\frac{C_2'}{q^{2-\varepsilon}}
$$
and how small is the quantity in these cases. (Note that
it follows from Dirichlet's theorem that an even stronger inequality,
$$
\biggl|\pi-\frac nq\biggr|<\frac1{q^2},
$$
happens for infinitely many pairs $n$ and $q$.)
The series (1) converges if and only if
$$
\sum_{n:|\pi-n/q|< C_2n^{-2+\varepsilon}}\frac1{n^5|\pi-n/q|^2}
$$
converges. We can replace the summation by summing over $q$
(again, for each term $\pi q\approx n$) and then sum the result
over all $q$, because the
terms corresponding to $|\pi-n/q|< C_2n^{-2+\varepsilon}$ do not
influence on the convergence:
$$
\sum_{q=1}^\infty\frac1{q^5|\pi-n/q|^2}
=\sum_{q=1}^\infty\frac1{q^3(\pi q-n)^2}
\qquad(2)
$$
where $n=n(q)$ is now chosen to minimize $|\pi-n/q|$.

Summarizing, *the original series converges if and only if the series in* (2)
*converges.*

It is already an interesting question of what can be said about the
convergence of (2) if we replace $\pi$ by other constant $\alpha$,
for example by a "generic irrationality". The series
$$
\sum_{q=1}^\infty\frac1{q^3(\alpha q-n)^2}
$$
for a real quadratic irrationality $\alpha$ converges because the best
approximations are $C_3/q^2\le|\alpha-n/q|\le C_4/q^2$, and they are achieved on
the convergents $n/q$ with $q$ increasing geometrically. A more delicate
question seems to be for $\alpha=e$, because one third of its convergents satisfies
$$
C_3\frac{\log\log q}{q^2\log q}<\biggl|e-\frac pq\biggr|< C_4\frac{\log\log q}{q^2\log q}
$$
(see, e.g., [C.S.Davis, *Bull. Austral. Math. Soc.* 20 (1979) 407--410]).
The number $e$, quadratic irrationalities, and even algebraic numbers
are `generic' in the sense that their irrationality exponent is known to be 2.
What about $\pi$?

The *irrationality exponent* $\mu=\mu(\alpha)$ of a real irrational number
$\alpha$ is defined as the infimum of exponents $\gamma$
such that the inequality $|\alpha-n/q|\le|q|^{-\gamma}$ has
only finitely many solutions in $(n,q)\in\Bbb Z^2$ with $q\ne0$.
(So, Dirichlet's theorem implies that $\mu(\alpha)\ge2$. At the same
time from metric number theory we know that it is 2 for almost all real irrationals.)
Assume that $\mu(\pi)>5/2$, then there are infinitely many
solutions to the inequality
$$
\biggl|\pi-\frac nq\biggr|<\frac{C_5}{q^{5/2}},
$$
hence infinitely many terms in (2) are bounded below by $1/C_5$, so that
the series diverges (and (1) does as well). Although the general
belief is that $\mu(\pi)=2$, the best known result of V.Salikhov (see
[this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23547/does-pi-contain-1000-consecutive-zeroes-in-base-10/23551#23551)
by Gerry and my comment)
only asserts that $\mu(\pi)<7.6064\dots$,.

I hope that this explains the problem of determining the behavior of the series in question.

Comment: So am I right in reading this as saying that the series is expected to converge?

Comment: Lev, yes, this is the expectation.

Comment: why don't you write $|\pi q - n(q)|$ in (2) ? it would be clearer

Comment: Hmmm... Since $\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{cesaro lim }} (\sin x)^2=1/2$, I definitely would suspect the series to converge.

Answer (score 34):

There is an even bigger reduction that can be done:

**Theorem:** The Flint Hills series converges if and only if the series
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{q_n^3 (q_n\pi - p_n)^2}
\qquad{(1)}
$$
converges, where $(p_n/q_n)_1^\infty$ is the sequence of convergents of $\pi$.

*Proof:* Let
$$
S = \sum_{q = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{q^3 (q\pi - p)^2},
\qquad{(2)}
$$
where $p\in\mathbb N$ is chosen to minimize $|q\pi - p|$. As Wadim Zudilin argued, the Flint Hills series converges if and only if $S$ converges. Now consider the unimodular lattice $\Lambda = \{(q,q\pi - p) : p,q\in\mathbb Z\}$. We can rewrite $S$ as
$$
S = \sum_{\substack{(q,r)\in\Lambda^* \\ q > 0 \\ -1/2 < r < 1/2}} \frac{1}{q^3 |r|^2}\cdot
$$
Here $\Lambda^* = \Lambda\setminus\{\mathbf 0\}$. Next, using the identity
$$
\frac{1}{q^3 r^2} = \int_{s > q} \int_{t > r} \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{1}{s^3 t^2} \;dt\;ds
= \int_{s > 1} \int_{t > 0} \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{1}{s^3 t^2} [s > q][t > r] \;dt\;ds
$$
we get
$$
S = \int_{s > 1} \int_{t > 0} \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{1}{s^3 t^2} \sum_{\substack{(q,r)\in\Lambda^* \\ q > 0 \\ -1/2 < r < 1/2}}  [s > q][t > |r|] \;dt\;ds\\
= \int_{s > 1} \int_{t > 0} \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{1}{s^3 t^2} \#\big\{(q,r)\in\Lambda^* : 0 < q < s,\; |r| < \min(t,1/2)\big\}  \;dt\;ds.
\qquad{(3)}
$$
We can bound the integrand in two different ways, depending on whether or not
$$
N_{s,t} := \#\big\{(q,r)\in\Lambda^* : 0 < q < s,\; |r| < \min(t,1/2)\big\} \leq \max(0,3st - 1/2).
\qquad{(4)}
$$
If (4) holds, then it can be used to bound the entire integral; I leave it to the reader to verify that the resulting integral converges. So let us consider the cases where (4) fails.

Fix $s > 1$ and $t > 0$, and let $D_{s,t} = (-s,s)\times(-t,t)$. If $D_{s,t}$ contains two linearly independent elements of $\Lambda$, then $D$ contains a fundamental domain for $\Lambda$, say $F$; we have
$$
1 + 2N_{s,t} = \#(\Lambda\cap D_{s,t}) = \sum_{\mathbf x\in\Lambda\cap D_{s,t}} m(\mathbf x + F)
= m\left(\bigcup_{\mathbf x\in\Lambda\cap D_{s,t}}(\mathbf x + F)\right)
\leq m(2D_{s,t}) = 4st,
$$
which implies that (4) holds. Similarly, if $D_{s,t}\cap\Lambda = \{\mathbf 0\}$, then (4) holds.

So if we assume that (4) fails for some pair $(s,t)$, then we have $D_{s,t}\cap\Lambda = D_{s,t}\cap \mathbb Z\mathbf x$ for some $\mathbf x = (q,r)\in D_{s,t}\cap\Lambda^*$. It follows that
$$
\max(1,3st - 1/2) \leq N_{s,t} = \left\lfloor \min\left(\frac sq,\frac t{|r|}\right)\right\rfloor \leq \min\left(\frac sq,\frac t{|r|}\right)
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{st}{q|r|} \geq \min\left(\frac sq,\frac t{|r|}\right)^2 \geq \max(1,3st - 1/2)^2 \geq \max(1,3st - 1/2) \geq 2st,
$$
so $q|r| = q|q\pi - p| \leq 1/2$. A well-known theorem now implies that $p/q$ is a convergent of $\pi$, i.e. $(q,p) = (q_n,p_n)$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. So if we let
$$
\Lambda_c = \{(k q_n, k(q_n\pi - p_n)) : n,k\in\mathbb N\}
$$
then
$$
N_{s,t} = \#(\Lambda_c\cap D_{s,t}).
$$
In other words, the only points which are contributing to the integrand of (3) are points which come from $\Lambda_c$. Reversing the argument of (3) now gives
$$
S \leq C + \sum_{\substack{(q,r)\in\Lambda_c \\ q > 0 \\ -1/2 < r < 1/2}} \frac{1}{q^3 |r|^2},
$$
where $C < \infty$ is a constant describing an upper bound on the contribution to the integral (3) of pairs $(s,t)$ satisfying (4). Thus,
$$
S \leq C + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k q_n)^3 (k(q_n \pi - p_n))^2}
= C+\zeta(5)\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{q_n^3 (q_n \pi - p_n)^2}\cdot
$$
It follows that (1) converges if and only if (2) converges.

---

If this proof was too technical to follow, I'll try to summarize the main ideas: First of all, any rational number $p/q$ which is not a convergent of $\pi$ must satisfy $q|q\pi - p| > 1/2$ (this is a well-known fact). By itself this fact isn't enough to guarantee that the terms coming from non-convergents won't make the series (2) diverge, since you end up comparing it with the harmonic series, which (just barely) diverges. But that's just the crudest possible bound: *most* rationals $p/q$ will satisfy $q|q\pi - p| \gg 1$. Since (2) involves a summation over *all* $q$, there will be a lot of "averaging", and so the "spikes" which occur when $q|q\pi - p|$ is small will be washed out in the long run. In order to formalize this you need to talk about lattices and fundamental domains - basically, the idea is that the number of intersection points of a lattice with a convex centrally symmetric region is about the same as the area of the region except for certain exceptional cases; these exceptional cases turn out to correspond to the convergents of $\pi$.

**Corollary:**
If the exponent of irrationality of $\pi$ is strictly less than $5/2$, then the Flint Hills series converges.
*Proof:* If $\mu(\pi) < 5/2$, then there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all but finitely many $n$, we have
$$
|q_n \pi - p_n| \geq q_n^{-3/2 + \varepsilon}.
$$
This gives the following upper bound for (1):
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{q_n^3 (q_n^{-3/2 + \varepsilon})^2} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{q_n^{2\varepsilon}}\cdot
$$
But since the sequence $(q_n)_1^\infty$ must grow at least exponentially fast, this series converges.

Answer (score 29):

Wadim Zudilin's answer is further extended in http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5100 
(Max A. Alekseyev, On convergence of the Flint Hills series).