# $\liminf n|\sin n|$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

$\liminf n|\sin n|$

Has this problem been solved? I looked up in some literature and didn't find the answer.

Comment: This is not a research-level question. Please read the faq for suggestions of sites that would be more appropriate for your question.

Comment: Your question in a more general form was already discussed: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24579/ .