# Proof that $\pi$ has infinitely many $1$s

Tags: nt.number-theory

I understand that there is currently no proof in any base for whether $\pi$ is normal or disjunctive.

Are there any proofs of whether specific sequences of numbers are infinitely occurring in $\pi$? For instance, is there a formal proof that 1 is infinitely occurring in the decimal expansion of $\pi$?

Comment: Well, I can think of a proof in base 2....

Comment: No, no such results have been proven.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the state of our ignorance about the normality of pi?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51853/what-is-the-state-of-our-ignorance-about-the-normality-of-pi) or [Does pi contain 1000 consecutive zeroes (in base 10)?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/23547)

Comment: It's not known whether the decimal digits of $\pi$ are eventually all $0$s and $2$s.

Comment: We do know that there exists a $10^{100}$-length sequence of digits that appears infinitely often in the decimal expansion of $\pi$ (and $10^{100}$ can be replaced by any other positive integer), but this is true for any infinite sequence of decimal digits . . .

Comment: @SamHopkins In base 2, every real number has *a* binary expansion which contains infinitely many 1's, since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty2^{-k}=1$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Can you please add a reference?

Comment: What does "disjunctive" mean in this context?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Means every finite digit sequence appears (equivalently, appears infinitely often) -- see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sequence#Rich_numbers). Related is "lexicon" -- see [*The typical number is a lexicon*](http://tzamfirescu.tricube.de/TZamfirescu-142.pdf) by Calude/Zamfirescu (1998). While normal numbers are full measure (large in one way) and meager (small in another way), the disjunctive numbers are measure zero and meager and smaller still -- see [this 19 February 2003 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/bLTYU8FDSZU/m/uP0ajDIVw04J).

Comment: @Dave, if a number is normal, then every finite digit sequence appears, so it's disjunctive. The normals are a subset of the disjunctives, no?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Yes. I wondered whether I should be writing something like this after 4 hours of sleep, but I did it anyway. What's small (measure zero & meager, even $\sigma$-porous) is the set of non-disjunctive numbers. There is a dichotomy of Lebesgue measure and Baire category for normal numbers: Most numbers ARE normal (Lebesgue measure) and most numbers are NOT normal (Baire category; indeed, "NOT" in a very strong way -- see [Olsen](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004104007601) and [Stylianou](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.02202)). However, most (both ways) numbers are disjunctive.

Comment: Compare a related problem for $\sqrt{2}$, which is a bit more accessible: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.01722.